# Binary Integer Programming

Tags: binary, integer-programming

I need to form teams. There are 8 projects and 60 students.
Each project has different requirements.
For example, out of 5 total requirements, project 1 has 2 requirements: must have a programmer and must have an analyst

Project 2 has 1 requirement: must have a programmer

Project 3 has 5 requirements: must have programmer, analyst, DB admin, manager, accountant

All the way to project 8.

Each student has a personality and skills. Each student has 5 possible skills:
Students 1 has 2 skills: programmer, accountant
Student 2 has 4 skills: programmer, accountant, analyst, DB admin

All the way to student 60

Each student also has a personality from 5 possible traits:
Student 1 has: 1/10 score on organization, 9/10 on creative thinking, 6/10 on creativity, 4/10 on teamwork, 5/10 on helpfulness

Student 2 has: 3/10 score on organization, 2/10 on creative thinking, 7/10 on creativity, 10/10 on teamwork, 9/10 on helpfulness

All the way to student 60

Putting a student with high creativity with a student high in teamwork is desired. Student with high level of helpfulness with a student low in creativity is desired.

How do I choose my teams?

Comment: `I need to form teams for a project. There are 8 projects and 60 students.[...]` I don't believe you, sorry...

Comment: ^ @DavidC.Ullrich this is a problem....not my real world problem but the one I am trying to solve....I've been at this for hours and I am trying different techniques with Excel Solver, but I just don't know what to do...I have tried in Excel Solver to setup team size constraints and project constraints using binary variables but how do I make sure the personality types are optimum as much as they can be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need 480 variables of the form $P01S01$ to $P08S60$.

These variables must be integer variables equal to 0 or 1.

$P03S40=1$ means that student 40 is allocated to project 40.

$P03S40=0$ means that student 40 is not allocated to project 40.

You will need up to 5 constraints for each project.

So if project 14 needs at least one programmer you need to set $P14S01+P14S08+P14S45+... \geq 1$ where students 1, 8, 45 etc are programmers.

That's the easy bit. The harder bit is in defining your objective function.

To encourage high creativity and high teamwork you might want to multiply together the creativity and teamwork scores for all the students in each project and add these to the objective function.

If the creativity score (value from 1 to 10 - zero causes problems) for students 01 to 60 is given by the variable $C01$ to $C60$ and the teamwork score is given by the variable $T01$ to $T60$ then the product can be found by evaluating: $C01^{P01S01} \times C02^{P01S02} \times ... C60^{P01S60} \times T01^{P01S01} \times T02^{P01S02} \times ... T60^{P01S60}$

To encourage the combination of low creativity and high helpfulness you might want to multiply together the "uncreativity" = 11-creativity and the helpfulness scores for all the students in each project and add these to the objective function.

If the creativity score (value from 1 to 10 - zero causes problems) for students 01 to 60 is given by the variable $C01$ to $C60$ and the helpfulness score is given by the variable $H01$ to $H60$ then the product can be found by evaluating: $(11-C01)^{P01S01} \times (11-C02)^{P01S02} \times ... (11-C60)^{P01S60} \times H01^{P01S01} \times H02^{P01S02} \times ... H60^{P01S60}$

Comment: the problem might be that C^P would no longer make this an integer program...I have to do this using integer programing only.

Comment: Definitely not IP as you say...

Comment: is there a way I could do this using IP only?

Comment: I'm trying to think. Maybe add a "total creativity and teamwork" constraint for each project: $C01\times P01S01+C02\times P01S02+...+C60\times P01S60+T01\times P01S01+T02\times P01S02+...+T60\times P01S60\geq x$

Comment: Then add a "total uncreativity and helpfulness" constraint for each project: $(11-C01)\times P01S01+(11-C02)\times P01S02+...+(11-C60)\times P01S60+T01\times P01S01+T02\times P01S02+...+T60\times P01S60\geq y$

Comment: ... and maximise $x+y$

Comment: you're amazing!

Comment: Did it work? I'd like to see your spreadsheet implementation of it.

Comment: the problem I see is that although the uncreativity and helpfuness constraint adds value to people who rank low in those stats, the desired goal is to pair-up the low creativity people with high creativity, so I don't see how the objective function will try to pair up the low creativity with high creativity. I've entered the solution into Solver but have been constantly trying to figure out how to make it desirable for the low creativity to be with high creativity.

Comment: I am thinking (CS2-CS1)*P1S1*P1S2 <---- You want a high creativity with low creativity and you have the two binary integers P1S1*P1S2 to ensure student 1 and 2 are matched if their creativity is high. Do the same for teamwork to make sure an anti-team pairs with a high team student. Then you add them as a Sum and that's the objective function.